# App goes to the background after running onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to log in to my app. On returning from the login activity, the following `onActivityResult`-override prints `Here1-1`, which is as expected. However, immediately after, the activity finishes, which is not what I want. I feel really lost, does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Here" + Integer.toString(requestCode) + Integer.toString(resultCode));
            }
        case RC_START_APP:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_LOGOUT) {
                signout();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cases need a `break` to stop execution so they don't fall through to the next case.  Your activity is actually just finishing due to executing the `finish()` in the second `RC_START_APP` case.

```java
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Here" + Integer.toString(requestCode) + Integer.toString(resultCode));
            }
            break;  // add this break
        case RC_START_APP:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_LOGOUT) {
                signout();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
            break;  // add this break
    }
```